# Why does my font not appear on some computers? But i can look at other fonts on different websites that i don't have installed?

Tags: html, fonts

Don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I am quite new to html, have made a complete site and uploaded to web server.

But i tried visiting the site on another device, and the font shows differently, but then when i go onto a website which has a different font it shows fine on their site.

Am i doing something wrong?

Cheers

Adam

Comment: did you create a `@fontface` in your `CSS` file ? and upload the font file to your server

Comment: No i didn't how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Because the computer doesn't have that font, and you didn't include the font to download, just an instruction as to which one to use.

The CSS `@fontface` instruction lets you direct a browser to a file with a font.

A simpler and lighter approach, is to suggest back-ups. E.g. Instead of:

```
font-family: arial;
```

You could use:

```
font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
```

The first will try to use Arial, and if it isn't available, will just use the default font for the browser (which could be a serif font like Times, for example).

The second will try to use Arial. If that's not available, it will try to use Verdana. If that's not available, it will try to use the default sans-serif font for the browser, which should at least be closer than a serif font.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial on how to create custom fonts on a website.

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

It will also explain which types of fonts are compatible on certain browsers